# AWS Transcribtion Issue of file format

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-transcribe

I am new for using Amazon Transcribe . I upload a audio in mp3 format and save it my bucket . But when i paste the link in Transcribtion Job . Always got error "The media format provided does not match the detected media format" but my in drop down i choose mp3 and my audio file extension is also mp3.

Comment: I experienced the same issue with .mp3 file but it works if I convert it to a .wav file.